# Is it possible to return a jquery widget from a function?

Tags: jquery, widget

I am wondering if it's possible to return a jQuery widget instance from a function.  I've since figured out a completely different way to do what I want, so this is just to satisfy my own curiosity.

Say I have two widgets and one inherits from the other.  I also have some code that might have a childWidget, or it might have a parentWidget.  But all that matters is calling a method on the parent widget--in this case, doSomething().  Rather than writing if statements every time to figure out whether to call childWidget('doSomething') or parentWidget('doSomething'), can I write this code once, return the correct widget, and then call doSomething()?

A very rudimentary example:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Little widget test</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(function() {
        //create parentWidget with doSomething function
    $.widget( "custom.parentWidget", {
      options: {
        widgetName: 'parent'
      },
      _create: function() {
        this.element
          // add a class for theming
          .addClass( this.options.widgetName );
      },
      doSomething: function( event ) {
        alert(this.options.widgetName);

      }
    });

    //create child widget; just overrides the widgetName property
    $.widget( "custom.childWidget", $.custom.parentWidget, {
      options: {
        widgetName: 'child'
      }
    });

        //make an instance of each widget
    $( "#my-widget1" ).parentWidget();
    $( "#my-widget2" ).childWidget();

    //function to get the widget instance
    $.fn.getWidget = function() {
            if($(this).is('.parent'))
                return $(this).parentWidget();

            return $(this).childWidget();
        }; 

    //this does not work
    $( "#my-widget1" ).getWidget()('doSomething');

  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
  <div id="my-widget1">parent widget</div>
  <div id="my-widget2">child widget</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: because `return $(this).parentWidget()` does not return a widget instance it returns the jquery wrapper for `this` element ie the same object as `$(this)` - as you know jQuery works based on chaining

Comment: Also the public methods on a widget is called using `$( "#my-widget1" ).parentWidget('doSomething');`

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with all that.  My question is really whether or not you can get a handle on a widget independently of the element it's attached to.  I think the answer is no, but as I said, this is curiosity on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my tests, I'm fairly certain the answer to this is "no."

What I did settle on was funneling all calls to the widget through a common function, since I only need to make very simple calls to my widget, each containing one parameter:

```
$.fn.callMyWidget = function (params) {
    if ($(this).is('.parent')) {
        $(this).parentWidget(params);
    }
    else {
        $(this).childWidget(params);
    }
}

//so now I can do this:
$( "#my-widget1" ).callMyWidget('doSomething');
```